# How to vectorize this kernel?

Tags: c, performance, sse

I made this question in the middle of another one, and it seems that nobody will answer it in the previous topic.

My question is the following. I have been vectorizing one application with success. However, for this particular kernel:

```
inline int cFunction(Node** A, Node* B){

    long dot = 0, i;

    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
            dot += (*A)->data[i] * B->data[i];

    if(abs(2 * dot) <= B->norm)
            return 0;

    long q = round((double) dot / B->norm);

    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
            (*A)->data[i] -= q * B->data[i];

    (*A)->norm = (*A)->norm + q * q * B->norm - 2 * q * dot;

    return 1;

}
```

I was only able to vectorize the first loop. If I put icpc to run this code, with:

```
 icpc *.c *.h -g -O2 -msse4.2 -vec-report=1
```

I have the following report:

main.c(558): (col. 9) remark: LOOP WAS VECTORIZED.

main.c(566): (col. 2) remark: LOOP WAS VECTORIZED.

Which tells me that the icpc actually vectorizes the code. Now, if I hand vectorize the first loop I have a good (perfect?) speedup factor for **ints**. This tells me that the compiler is not doing a good job at vectorizing this (especially because if I use **short** s the performance is the same). However, for the second loop, I get no whatsoever performance gains if I hand vectorize it like this:

```
    const int q = round((double) dot / B->norm) ;

    int32_t * pA = (*A)->data;
    int32_t * const pB = B->data;

    const __m128i vecQi = _mm_set1_epi32(q);

    __m128i vecResi, vecPi, vecCi, vecQCi;

    for(i=0;i<SIZE-3;i+=4){
            vecPi = _mm_load_si128((__m128i *)&(pA)[i] );
            vecCi = _mm_load_si128((__m128i *)&(pB)[i] );
            vecQCi = _mm_mullo_epi32(vecQi,vecCi);
            vecResi = _mm_sub_epi32(vecPi,vecQCi);
            _mm_store_si128((__m128i *) ((pA) + i), vecResi );
    }

    for(;i<SIZE;i++)
            pA[i] -= q * pB[i];

    (*A)->norm = (*A)->norm + q * q * B->norm - 2 * q * dot;
```

Does anyone have a clue of why I am not getting performance gains by vectorizing the second kernel?

Thanks.

Comment: Compare the disassembly of each.  Profile the execution to look for which code dominates the cycles, whether/if there are pipeline stalls, branch misprediction, etc.

Comment: From my experience, trying to vectorize anything with such a small computation/memory-access ratio is hopeless. I'm surprised you're getting any speedup at all for the first one.

Comment: This is the dominant kernel of the application, but the rest is totally memory bound (searches in several data structures).

Comment: I don't use to work with vectorization, but my idea would be to help the compiler with this function signature: 
`inline int cFunction(Node* restrict * A, const Node* restrict B)` If A and B don't overlap

Comment: In your previous questions you mentioned that `SIZE` is quite small, and so I suggested that you use integer division to generate your constant `q` rather than a potentially expensive call to `round()`, since this could easily be as costly as the entire SIMD loop for small values of `SIZE`.

Comment: @Paul yes, I tried, but the values get different and the algorithm doesn't converge.

Comment: You just need to be careful about how you do the integer division - if you want to match the result of `round()` with floating point values then care has to be take with the rounding constant in an integer division. What are the typical values and ranges for `dot` and `currentNode->norm` ?

Comment: @PaulR Can you give me an example, please?

Comment: Typically you might do something like this: `q = (d + n / 2) / n;` but the exact details will depend on the ranges of `d` and `n` and whether either of them can be negative.

Comment: @a3mlord do the values pointed to by A and B overlap?

Comment: @PaulR They vary a lot, but B->norm will be >2000000, whereas q are about the same, but they can be either negative or positive.

Comment: @Buella Gábor No, they never overlap.

Comment: So try using he restrict keyword

Comment: It was invented for these cases of optimizations http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict

Comment: OK - if you need to handle +/- rounding correctly then you would need something more like: `q = d >= 0 ? (d + n / 2) / n : (d - n / 2) / n;`.

Comment: @PaulR Didn't modify performance. :/

Comment: OK - what throughput are you getting, i.e. how many clocks per element ? Let's compare this figure with theoretical best case.

Comment: @a3mlord If you are still not sure what overlapping influences, let me tell what my guess is: your compiler doesn't know that `**A` and `*B` can't overlap, so it must take care of such cases when `A[3]` is the same as `B[4]` , so after `A[3] = q*B[3]` the value of `B[4]` is not the same as was before. This behavior would change with vectorization, and your compiler doesn't want to change the functioning of your code. So it doesn't vectorize. But you can let your compiler know there won't be any overlap.

Comment: @Buella Gábor I've tried it, it doesn't work. The compiler argues that it is vectorizing the code, but performance doesn't change.

Comment: @Paul It is very difficult to say, I am doing tons of other operations, it is very difficult to isolate that. Should I measure and print the time of all these operations?

Comment: Ideally you should always have unit test harnesses for any critical routines so that you can test and benchmark them in isolation. For now though you could just collect timestamps before/after the critical routine and then convert the elapsed time to clocks / element.

Comment: @Paul I will isolate and benchmark them, and I'll get back here tomorrow (in about ~16h from now). Thanks.

Comment: I have a hunch that the second loop might not be performance relevant in the first place. It follows after a conditional early return. If that return is triggered in most cases, you won't see any performance gain from optimizing the second loop. Try outputting the number of calls to the functions and the number of times that the second loop is actually entered. If the later is only a fraction of the former, forget about that second loop.

Comment: @cmaster The second loop is executed 90% of the times the function is called. On top of that, I use the very same kernel alone in another part of the code (non-conditional). This is one of the bottlenecks of my app.

Comment: Sorry for not replying sooner. The 90% is an important fact to know, but I guess we need some more data to get anywhere near answering your question: What is the value of `SIZE`? And how many Nodes do you have typically? Do you call your function on all possible pairs in turn? And why do you access node `A` via a double pointer?

Comment: @cmaster I want so SIZE to fluctuate between 80 and 150. The number of Nodes varies a lot, but I have at least thousands or tens of thousands. Yes, I call the function on every possible pair. A is accessed via a double pointer because it gets modified within the function (Second loop and norm).

Comment: I confess, I can't make head or tail out of your observation that vectorization does not speed up the second loop. Your numbers tell me that all required data is definitely in L1 cache when the second loop is entered, i. e. its performance is not limited by the memory bus. In fact, all data fits into the last level cache. In short, there is no reason why it shouldn't get faster with vectorization. Concerning the double pointer: you don't need it because you don't modify the pointer itself. Instead, you should declare `B` as `const Node*` to declare that you'll not change that node.

Comment: @cmaster You're right about the double pointer. On top of that, I messed up. The second loop is executed 10% of the times that the function is known, not 90%. However, it would still make a difference to have a vec. vs a non vectorized code, no?

Comment: @PaulR I believe that the second kernel is not that important (I'll post the numbers today). Thus, would you be so nice and comment on the other topic, with the name "int vs short vectorization", please? The Idonotexit user helped me a lot, but I need to go further. Any comment will be highly appreciated.

Comment: OK - let me know the measured throughout in elements per clock - that will tell us how much further it can potentially be optimised.

Comment: @PaulR For the loop in the other topic, with the name "int vs short vectorization", in terms of CPE - cicles per element - I have 3.20 cicles per element, when size is 70; I'll get the numbers of this one;

Comment: That's very high - it should be < 1 - unless you mean 3.2 clocks per vector ?

Comment: @PaulR, yes, I mean 3.20 per element, where "element" means a whole vector. Please see the code here: http://pastebin.com/LKpbZvbc - should I migrate to AVX?

Comment: @PaulR BTW, I get (slightly) better performance when I align the memory to 8 than to 16 - don't get why.

Comment: OK - an element typically refers to a scalar element, so that throughout is normalised regardless of SIMD vector size. So if you have 3.2 clocks per vector, and 8 elements per vector, you're getting a throughput of around 0.4 clocks per element (and presumably around 0.8 clocks per element with the 32 bit version ?).

Comment: The bad news though is that I don't think you're going to improve on this much. To optimise further you need to start looking at how these functions are called and look at whether the cost of load/store operations can be amortised across a greater number of ALU operations, since you are currently doing very little computation relative to I/O.

Comment: @PaulR Let me test what happens with ints, but that is the problem, the throughput will be similar, not the double. I'll post the numbers once I have them.

Comment: Yes, I think it needs a new topic - summarise all the above in a new question and we can take it from there. (P.S. It can't be 0.07 cycles/element - I guess you mean 0.7?).

Comment: @PaulR VERY interesting results. I basically put both kernels in a file, the first (topic "int vs short vectorization") vectorized the second (here in this topic) not vectorized. I measured CPEs and execution time. I did with both g++ 4.6.1 and icpc. I'll comment the first loop here. The results were: the first kernel, vectorized, runs better with g++ - 0.073132 CPE vs 0.077022 with icpc, for ints. For shorts, I have 0.076978 CPE with icpc and 0.073510 with g++; This means that the performance doesn't change. As for the second loop, I had very interesting results - should I open a new topic?

Comment: @PaulR, I've updated my commment - I'll open a new topic called "vectorization potential". Thanks!

Comment: @PaulR I am preparing the new topic. No, I really had 0.07x. Are the measurements wrong? What I did was to count the time of the whole loop and do: CPE = (time*clocks)/(ITERATIONS)/DIMENSION, where DIMENSION is the size of the vectors. Ain't this right?

Comment: Depending on how you define ITERATIONS I think that already implies DIMENSION, so you're dividing by DIMENSION twice. As a sanity check, you have several instructions, therefore several clocks, per loop iteration, so if you have say, 3 clocks per loop iteration, and 8 elements per loop iteration, then the CPE would be 0.375 CPE. It's probably better to leave out DIMENSION and ITERATIONS altogether and just define it as time*clock_speed/N, where N is the number of elements in your data set.

Comment: ITERATIONS is the number of times I repeat the loop, whereas DIMENSION is the number of elements in the arrays. I think that I am doing this right, but I am also surprised with such a low number. BTW, without ITERATIONS the number is huge... I am doing the loops a LOT of times ( 5x9^10 );

Comment: @PaulR The results I have are definitely wrong. Each CPE is < 0.1 which is theoretically impossible. Even with shorts perfectly vectorized I'd have 0.125 CPE for one instruction of 1 cycle of latency.

Comment: Re-read what I wrote above - you are out by a factor of `DIMENSION`, because each *loop* iteration already takes `DIMENSION` into account. Use the alternate method I gave which avoids this confusion: `time*clock_speed/N`, where `N` is the number of (scalar) elements in your data set.

Comment: @PaulR I don't get it, sorry. What I have is: for(int i=0;i<ITERATIONS;i++){ for(int o=0;o<DIMENSION;o++) A[o] = q*B[o]; } If I output time*clock_speed/DIMENSION, I have a huge number of cycles. The clock speed is 2.6GHz, which I wrote as 2.6 * pow(10,9); My Iterations are just a way of guaranteeing that I do this multiple times and I have solid numbers. Sry, I don't get it...

Comment: Well obviously something is wrong in either your measurement or your calculation. Until you can get a reliable result there's not much more that I can add.

Comment: @PaulR I was sick for a while. I got the correct CPEs now, for both compilers and kernels, but I still find one thing odd. I have a speedup of 12x between the not-vectorized code and the vectorized code, with ints. While this is possible, I find it very odd. Between ints and shorts, the speedup is 1.39x, which seems very realistic.

Comment: Hope you're feeling better! 12x is suspicious - I would expect somewhere between 2.5x and 4x depending on CPU and size of data set.

Comment: @PaulR I really can't spot the problem (if there is any). With GCC, the speedups are within that range (3.2x), but with ICPC I get 12x. Also, the difference of performance of both compilers in the same, hand-vectorized code, is very different (1.5x speedup in ICPC). Can you take a quick look at the code, please? http://pastebin.com/aCgbHP80

Comment: I'm not at home right now so can't easily compile and run the code - I notice though that you are using unaligned loads for the INT case and aligned loads for the SHORT case? How much difference this makes depends on what CPU you are using.

Comment: OK - I took a quick look - one problem is that you are using `long` (64 bits typically) for `dot`, so the scalar implementation is not equivalent to the SIMD routines. Changing this to `int32_t` helps the compiler to vectorize the scalar loop much better.

Comment: @PaulR Very nice catches; If I change my dot to a int32_t, then I do have much more realistic numbers. This basically leads me to another thing... In my code, I am using **longs** because I except overflows in some parts. However, in my dot product kernel, I am not being coherent, because I am casting the result in vsum to a int32_t; As I didn't have problems so far, can I assume that I can change everything to ints and have no problems whatsoever?

Comment: It was easy to test - I _must_ use longs.